# accordion style on mobile and sidebar on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

This layout is what I have.

```xml
<div class="container" style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width: 25%;">
        <div class="collapsible-title is-active">Title 1
            <i class="fas fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="collapsible-title">Title 2
            <i class="fas fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 75%;">
        <div class="collapsible-content is-active">
            <h3>Title 1 Content</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="collapsible-content">
            <h3>Title 2 Content</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this script to switch tabs.

```js
$(".collapsible-title").on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("is-active").siblings(".collapsible-title").removeClass("is-active");
  $(".collapsible-content").eq($(this).index()).addClass("is-active").siblings(".collapsible-content").removeClass("is-active");
});
```

It displays correctly as sidebar view.
[image: Views]

Now on mobile view, I cant display it as accordion as the layout is not made that way.
I need to insert content-1 between tab-1 and tab-2 view.
I was thinking of moving content-1 div using javascript, but will also need to switch back to original when on desktop view.

There should be some better way, that I am not aware of.

I did try to do accordion first and then do desktop view, but the sidebar didnt work as expected so switched to this.
Note: using CSS and javascript (no-bootstrap: it is the requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @media (max-width: 360px) like this.
it works at mobile (browser width max360)

```js
var activeNum = 0;

$(".mo-title").on("click", function() {
  activeNum = $(this).index();    
  onAccordion(activeNum);
});

$(".pc-title").on("click", function(){
  activeNum = $(this).parent(".box").index();  
  onAccordion(activeNum);
});

function onAccordion(activeNum){
  console.log(activeNum);
  $(".mo-title").removeClass("active");
  $(".pc-title").removeClass("active");
  $(".mo-title").eq(activeNum).addClass("active");
  $(".pc-title").eq(activeNum).addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
.sidebar{
  flex:0 0 100px;
  background:beige;
  display:none;
}
.sidebar .mo-title{
  border:solid 1px #000;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  background:gray;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.sidebar .mo-title.active{
  color:yellow;
}
.content{
  flex:1;
  padding:10px;
}
.content .box p{
  display:none;
  margin:0;  
  padding:10px;
  border:solid 1px gray;
}
.content .box .pc-title{
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:gray;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.content .box .pc-title.active{
  color:yellow;
}
.content .box .pc-title.active + p{
  display:block;
}

@media (max-width: 360px) { 
  .sidebar{
     display:block;
  }
  .content .box .pc-title{
     display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="display: flex">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="mo-title active">Title 1
            <i class="fas fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="mo-title">Title 2
            <i class="fas fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="mo-title">Title 3
            <i class="fas fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box">
            <h3 class="pc-title active">Title 1 Content</h3>
            <p>
              1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3  class="pc-title">Title 2 Content</h3>
            <p>
              2. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3  class="pc-title">Title 3 Content</h3>
            <p>
              3. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```